# md-table flexible columns in Angular Material 2

Tags: angular-material2

How can i make the md-table columns flexible, that the width of each column is dynamically?

At the moment my table look like this.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a plunkr or similar.. impossible to know your markup ;)

Comment: as far as I can see there is no fixed width in the material2 demo?

Comment: Yep at the moment i have added a ellipsis to cut the text
here is a plunker with long text
https://plnkr.co/edit/AErBdLDBXnXweV13hH7F?p=preview

Comment: did you get it? I'm trying to do the same and its driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

I did set width on the `<md-cell>` using **fxFlex="123px"** for elements that i know they will be fixed like columns with handle icons, and just set **fxFlex** for the rest of the elements so they auto align.

same goes to `<md-header-cell>`

Comment: Thought you had the ellipsis part figured out and only needed the width definition part, so, along with fxFlex (which i couldnt import it in the plunkr) you also add this css and text is truncated;

`md-cell { white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; }
`

Answer (score 0):

@cucuru i found a little workaround over the CSS

```
.mat-column-COLUMNID {
   flex: 0 0 13%; //change the 13% with every width you need
}
```

with this little code you can change the width of each column, it will break the lines automatically.